# image processing- separating channels (without numpy)

Tags: python, image-processing

I haven't found a similar question with a solution here, so I'll ask your help.

I have to implement the function: divide_channels (image) Which receives an image (3D list) (whose dimensions are channels × columns × rows and returns a 3D list Dimensional, whose dimensions are columns × rows × channels, that is, a list of two-dimensional images that each one represents Single color channel.

There is a list of which is list of lists:

```
[[[4, 5]]]
```

As a final result I would like to split it by 2 separate lists of lists:

```
divide_channels([[[4, 5]]]) → [[[4]], [[5]]] 
divide_channels([[[0, 1, 2]]*2]*3) → [[[0]*2]*3, [[1]*2]*3, [[2]*2]*3]

By [[[0, 1, 2]]*2]*3 and [[[0]*2]*3, [[1]*2]*3, [[2]*2]*3], I mean [[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]], [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]], [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]] and [[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]], [[2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2]]], respectively.
```

I tried to create loops but I have nothing to share. Any ideas are appreciated. ( I am not allowed to use numpy).

Comment: Look into `numpy.reshape()`

Comment: As listed in the question-I am not allowed to use numpy.

Comment: Your example data doesn't quite seem to make sense in the context of 2D multi-channel images. Could you add a better example?

Comment: basically they want `cv.split()` but DIY code. in a previous question they attempted to write some code for this but that amounted to flattening the array and some misconceptions about python loops and indexing. -- oh and in this question the order of dimensions is backwards. they have (h,w,c) and want (c,h,w)

Comment: You're right, and what I did in a previous question was just out of desperation, I've been trying this question for a few hours without success.

Comment: `channel=img[:,:,0]`